# using Akka can we copy files from Remote system?

Tags: akka

on my system I am using akka framework. I need to copy files from remote system.
Can I use akka in my main system to copy required files from remote system?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read
[what this site is about](https://stackoverflow.com/about) and 
"[How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)" 
before asking a question.

Comment: I guess the question is what this remote system looks like: does it already provide some kind of interface to copy the file? If it offers for example sftp you might use the ftp adapter from the alpakka project to integrate with akka-stream. Or do you plan to install a service that makes that possible?

Answer (score 0):

> Can I use akka

is a pretty broad question.

- Can you send the files as actor messages? No, or well, in theory you could, but I wouldn't recommend it. Messages are supposed to be small and fast,
  not potentially large files. There's also a (configurable) size limit for remote messages, messages that exceed the limit will not be sent.
- Can you create a side-channel and use e.g. [Akka HTTP](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/current/scala/http/) to stream the
  file from one node to another? Yes, you surely can.

Answer (score 0):

If you necessarily want to use akka for this, I'd consider using akka-streams:

http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/java/stream/stream-io.html

So you can run a File -> TCP stream on the source host and a TCP -> File stream on the target host.

However, this way of doing it is very low-level and error-prone. I would strongly suggest using some higher level technologies for this, e.g. Kafka with Kafka Connect.

Examples here:

https://howtoprogram.xyz/2016/07/10/apache-kafka-connect-example/

and here (I'd skip the avro part, then you don't need schema-registry):

http://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/quickstart.html